# I there a microsoft resource for translated Windows Winapi/Win32/system error messages?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, translation, error-code

It is easy enough to find the lists of system errors in English:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

However, quite often users report the error messages (without any number of course) in their native language (most often german for me, but we had italian or french cases also).
Is there a translated list of these error texts as reported by windows, so that one would be able to search for these texts (and their corresponding error number) for non-english texts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Microsoft's Language Portal](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Default.aspx).

They have [a form](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx) where you can look up translation of specific terms or phrases from English to any language or vice versa, and if you have MSDN or TechNet subscription you can [download complete UI translations](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Translations.aspx).

Comment: Amazing. It actually works! :-) Note: The title page only allows to enter an English search term, but when you switch to the search page, you can also search the non-en language term.

Answer (score 1):

There is none that I know of. However, you can build your own using the [`FormatMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351.aspx) API. You need to supply the error code as the `dwMessageId` and provide the desired `LANGID`.